# Python PyQt6 QStyledItemDelegate setting foreground text color

Tags: python, pyqt6

I'm trying to set the foreground color of one column of my TableView.  I am trying with `initStyleOption()` of the `QStyledItemDelegate()` class.  I was able to get the color to be red via the `paint()` method, but it drew two items in the way I did it.  Here's what I'm currently trying to do:

```
class MainGUI(qt.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(653, 500)
        frame = qt.QFrame()
        self.setCentralWidget(frame)
        self.grid = qt.QGridLayout(frame)
        self.model = QStandardItemModel()
        self.view = qt.QTableView()
        self.view.setModel(self.model)
        self.view.setItemDelegate(TableDisplay())
        self.grid.addWidget(self.view, 0, 0)
        lst1 = [QStandardItem('testing...')] * 10
        lst2 = [QStandardItem('more...')] * 10
        self.model.appendColumn(lst1)
        self.model.appendColumn(lst2)

class TableDisplay(qt.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def initStyleOption(self, option, index):
        super(TableDisplay, self).initStyleOption(option, index)
        if index.column() == 1:
            option.palette.setColor(QPalette.ColorRole(0), Qt.GlobalColor.red)
```

How can I get column 1 to be red, and not black?  With the above code, there is no change.  No errors (which I could work with), but no change in presentation.  What am I missing?

Comment: The role for entry widgets (item views, edit fields, etc) is `Text`, not `WindowText`. Change to `QPalette.ColorRole(6)` or `QPalette.ColorRole.Text`. Also, the syntax of the lists is wrong: you are creating lists that contain the *same* item referenced 10 times, which is wrong since items are unique. Change to `[QStandardItem('testing') for i in range(10)]`. Finally, it's usually good practice to create the delegates with the view as parent: `self.view.setItemDelegate(TableDisplay(self.view))`

Comment: Thanks, @musicamante .  To the rescue again.  My example above was an MRE, so the working code is different.  I just wanted to whip something up for the boards (re: the list passed to my model).  But, you taught me something about that, too.  Tested, and all is good now.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: No worries. Just remember, an MRE is not just for "us", it's for anybody, including those who are providing it. 90% of the times the very attempt in providing a *valid* MRE solves the issue (see [rubber duck debugging](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)) because it forces the author to change the point of view and understand where the problem actually is, but it's also an incredible resource of understanding and finding out about aspect that were unknown or given for granted. A proper MRE has to be carefully tested (to ensure its *reproducibility*), and there's where you learn too.